# Query no Sequelize separando Mês e Ano

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Olá, pessoal. Desculpe se minha pergunta parecer meio boba, mas estou começando agora e fazer essa query tá dando um nó na minha cabeça kkk

Seguinte, estou construindo um sistema para gerenciar os vales (adiantamentos) da empresa. Já criei o sistema de login usando o express-session e está funcionando legal. Só que agora preciso criar uma página que a pessoa veja todos os vales dele no mês atual. Por exemplo: Se eu entrasse hoje (15/08/2020), eu veria todos os vales que eu pedi em Agosto de 2020. Fazer a query procurando pelos vales correspondentes ao id do usuário eu já consegui tranquilo da seguinte forma:

```
const finantialController = {
financeiro: async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const vales = await Vales.findAll({
            where:
                {
                userId: req.session.user.id,
                },
            include: [{model:User}]
        })
        res.render('finantial/financeiro', {vales: vales})
```

Esse trecho do código tá funcionando lindamente, mas eu não sei como armazenar a data atual (talvez vou ter que fazer isso através do datetime) e como separar o mês e o ano da minha database e comparar com o datetime. Eu já tenho os timestamps na database, então eu usaria a coluna "createdAt". Já li a documentação, já tentei algumas formas, já pesquisei bastante mas infelizmente não cheguei em nenhuma solução. Se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço muito!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tá um pouco confuso mas vou tentar ajudar! a variável **vales** deve retornar um array com as colunas referentes ao ID informado, certo?!

para pegar o mês e o ano você pode utilizar o Date passando o valor do createAt:

```
const date = new Date("2020-05-06 05:20:30")
console.log(date.getMonth(), date.getYear())
```

Mesma coisa para pegar o ano e mês atual, basta remove o **"2020-05-06 05:20:30"**

Feito isso você vai ter as datas da tabela e atual. depois você pode fazer uma comparação percorrendo o array com um **MAP** e comparando os valores com **IF**.

Comment: Cara, muitíssimo obrigado! Vc me deu uma ótima ideia e consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte: 
Criei uma variável TODAY que recebe a data de hoje, depois criei uma MONTH que recebe today.gethMonth(), depois outra chamada year que recebe today.getYear(). 
Então criei uma função (SAMEMONTHANDYEAR) que primeiro filtra pelo mês, depois pelo ano e retorna esse valor.
E aí peguei aquele array ali VALES e apliquei um filter com a função. Deu certinho.
Muito obrigado, man!

Comment: Disponha! se você puder marcar como resposta útil eu ficaria feliz